# What does the word "otherwise" mean in this passage?

Tags: word-meaning

Does "otherwise" here mean "If it can survive the changes"?

> Whatever is true now should be discoverable now, and describable in terms that are not an outright affront to the rest of what we knew about the world. By this measure, the entire project of religion seems perfectly backward. **It cannot survive the changes** that have come over us-culturally, technologically, and even ethically. **Otherwise, there are few reasons to believe** that we will survive it.

Source: [The End of Faith](https://www.beliefnet.com/faiths/secular-philosophies/the-problem-with-religious-moderates.aspx) by Sam Harris

Comment: I read it as *Even if this project of religion survives the changes, we, as individuals, probably won't...*

Comment: I've had a hard time to understand you: The grammar is plain while the logic is plainly problematic to me.   Why we won't? I noticed that "it" in "survive it" refers back to the entire project of religion while "we won't" seems to mean "we won't survive the changes.. Hence the problem of understanding remains.

Comment: "there are few reasons to believe that we will survive it" means "there are not many/almost no reasons to believe in our survival"

Comment: It makes it much clearer. Thank you.

Comment: OP, if you're noticing Sam Harris' problematic logic, then you are doing better than many native speakers. :)

Comment: What @AndrewTobilko said. ***Otherwise*** here simply refers to the possibility that the preceding sentence might ***not*** be true (i.e. - if religion ***does*** survive, there are few reasons to believe that ***we*** will survive ***religion***).